# Array version of partial permutation generator in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a VBA code to arrange k-element subset of an n-set into some sequence. In other word, I'm trying to list all of [k-permutations of n](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) member set. For example, let's try to list all of [2-permutations of set **{A,B,C}**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Permutations%5B%7BA,B,C%7D,2%5D) where each characters are located in the cells of `Range("A1:C1")`. Here are all the permutations:

```
{A,B}       {A,C}       {B,A}       {B,C}       {C,A}       {C,B}
```

The following code to implement the above task works fine if there's no duplicate in each of characters of data input:

```
Sub Permutation()
Dim Data_Input As Variant, Permutation_Output As Variant
Dim Output_Row As Long, Last_Column As Long

Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Clear
Last_Column = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Data_Input = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1", Cells(1, Last_Column))))

k = InputBox("Input the value of k for P(" _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " , k) where k is an integer between 2 and " _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " inclusive.", "Permutation", 1)

If k >= 2 And k <= UBound(Data_Input) Then
    Output_Row = 2
    ReDim Permutation_Output(1 To k)
    Call Permutation_Generator(Data_Input, Permutation_Output, Output_Row, 1)
Else
    MsgBox "The input [" & k & "] is invalid. The input must be an integer between 2 and " _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " inclusive."
End If

End Sub

Function Permutation_Generator(Data_Input As Variant, Permutation_Output As Variant, _
                               Output_Row As Long, Output_Index As Integer)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, P As Boolean

For i = 1 To UBound(Data_Input)
    P = True
    For j = 1 To Output_Index - 1
        If Permutation_Output(j) = Data_Input(i) Then
            P = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If P Then
        Permutation_Output(Output_Index) = Data_Input(i)
        If Output_Index = k Then
            Output_Row = Output_Row + 1
            Range("A" & Output_Row).Resize(, k) = Permutation_Output
        Else
            Call Permutation_Generator(Data_Input, Permutation_Output, Output_Row, Output_Index + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Though the above code has not perfectly worked fine for processing the duplicate data, but I am trying to improve its performance by putting the input data and finding all of k-permutations in arrays. Here is the code in the array version:

```
Option Explicit
Public k As Variant, Permutation_Table As Variant
Sub Permutation()
Dim Data_Input, Permutation_Output
Dim Output_Row As Long, Last_Column As Long

Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Clear
Last_Column = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Data_Input = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1", Cells(1, Last_Column))))

k = InputBox("Input the value of k for P(" _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " , k) where k is an integer between 2 and " _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " inclusive.", "Permutation", 1)

ReDim Permutation_Table(1 To Output_Row - 2, 1 To k)

If k >= 2 And k <= UBound(Data_Input) Then
    Output_Row = 2
    ReDim Permutation_Output(1 To k)
    Call Permutation_Generator(Data_Input, Permutation_Output, Output_Row, 1)
Else
    MsgBox "The input [" & k & "] is invalid. The input must be an integer between 2 and " _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " inclusive."
End If
Range("A3", Cells(Output_Row - 2, k)) = Permutation_Table
End Sub

Function Permutation_Generator(Data_Input As Variant, Permutation_Output As Variant, _
                               Output_Row As Long, Output_Index As Integer)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, P As Boolean

For i = 1 To UBound(Data_Input)
    P = True
    For j = 1 To Output_Index - 1
        If Permutation_Output(j) = Data_Input(i) Then
            P = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If P Then
        Permutation_Output(Output_Index) = Data_Input(i)
        If Output_Index = k Then
            Output_Row = Output_Row + 1
            For n = 1 To k
            Permutation_Table(Output_Row, n) = Permutation_Output(n)
            Next n
        Else
            Call Permutation_Generator(Data_Input, Permutation_Output, Output_Row, Output_Index + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Unfortunately, I encountered some errors when trying to fix it. The last error I encountered is the run-time error '7'. I'm hoping someone here could help me to fix it and to better it in order to make a good partial anagram generator, i.e. it must be able to work if there are the duplicate characters. For example, let's test to list all of characters in my name: **ANA**. [The output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Permutations%5B%7BA,N,A%7D,3%5D) should be **ANA**, **AAN**, and **NAA**, but my code returns nothing. For [2-permutations of my name](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Permutations%5B%7BA,N,A%7D,2%5D) should be **AN**, **AA**, and **NA** yet my code returns **AN**, **NA**, **AN**, and **NA**. *I'd be eternally grateful if someone here could help me.*

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the right code to obtain all of k-permutations using the array method **provided** there's no duplicate data in the input. The following code works fine and pretty fast.

```
Dim k As Long, Permutation_Table
Sub Permutation()
Dim Data_Input, Permutation_Output
Dim Output_Row As Long, Last_Column As Long, Array_Row As Long

Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Clear
Last_Column = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Data_Input = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1", Cells(1, Last_Column))))

k = InputBox("Input the value of k for P(" _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " , k) where k is an integer between 2 and " _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " inclusive.", "Permutation", 1)

Array_Row = WorksheetFunction.Fact(k) * WorksheetFunction.Combin(UBound(Data_Input), k)

ReDim Permutation_Table(1 To Array_Row, 1 To k)

If k >= 2 And k <= UBound(Data_Input) Then
    ReDim Permutation_Output(1 To k)
    Call Permutation_Generator(Data_Input, Permutation_Output, Output_Row, 1)
Else
    MsgBox "The input [" & k & "] is invalid. The input must be an integer between 2 and " _
    & UBound(Data_Input) & " inclusive."
End If
Range("A3").Resize(Array_Row, k) = Permutation_Table    'Use this line if UBound(Data_Input) < 10
End Sub

Function Permutation_Generator(Data_Input As Variant, Permutation_Output As Variant, _
                               Output_Row As Long, Output_Index As Integer)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, P As Boolean

For i = 1 To UBound(Data_Input)
    P = True
    For j = 1 To Output_Index - 1
        If Permutation_Output(j) = Data_Input(i) Then
            P = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If P Then
        Permutation_Output(Output_Index) = Data_Input(i)
        If Output_Index = k Then
            Output_Row = Output_Row + 1
            For n = 1 To k
                Permutation_Table(Output_Row, n) = Permutation_Output(n)
            Next n
            Debug.Print Join(Permutation_Output, ",")    'Optional, use this line as the output if UBound(Data_Input) > 9
        Else
            Call Permutation_Generator(Data_Input, Permutation_Output, Output_Row, Output_Index + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

**P.S.** I'm still hoping someone here comes up with a better version, either a shorter or quicker version.